# Пути к файлам

Tags: файлы, phpstorm

```
<?php 
include 'path/to/file.php'; // тут всё ок, при клике на file.php открывается файл 
$path_to_file = 'path/to/file.php'; // не ок, мб есть какая-то специальная  директива/phpdoc, которая скажет IDE, что это путь к файлу и нужно распарсить? 
?>
```

Comment: не думал, что мой вопрос будет кому-то непонятен. проблема в том, что при клике по file.php в строковой переменной $path_to_file IDE не открывает file.php для редактирования. вот я и пытаюсь ее научить это делать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно перейти к файлу, указанному как значение в строковой переменной, то есть вот такой способ:

1. Выберите часть строки, которую нужно считать путем к файлу
    1.а Выделите нужный участок мышкой
    1.б Расширяйте выделение от текущей позиции курсора с помощью **ctrl+shift+стрелка [влево|вправо]**
2. Нажмите **Ctrl+Shift+N** (откроется окно **Go to file** и выделенная строка подставится в фильтр)
3. Далее по ситуации: 
    3.а Клацнуть **Enter** (если одно совпадение)
    3.б Два раза кликнуть по нужной строке (если несколько совпадений)

После этих манипуляций файл откроется в новой вкладке.

Comment: @VenZell, способ интересный, но все происходит в 3 шага, а это очень долго. Легче воспользоваться Search Everywhere .

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, можно сократить до двух шагов, если вбивать имя вручную.  
Тут все ради того, чтобы автоматически подставить в фильтр значение из выделения и не писать его вручную.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. расчитывал конечно на немного другое

Answer (score 0):

Это нормально, ведь Вы создаете переменную с указанием типа данных string, в который вы можете запихнуть что угодно. Поэтому IDE не смысла распарсивать все строковые данные и вставлять туда линк.  Представьте, если в переменную вогнать целую страницу текста и IDE будет тратить свое время, чтобы найти там file.php и создать на него ссылку, это лишнее.
Используйте другую очень удобную фичу у phpStorm: быстро два раза жмете Shift и открывается хороший поиск по всему. Там пишите "file" и вам уже нужный результат будет выдан.

Comment: Так автор и ищет способ сказать phpstorm, что конкретно эта переменная содержит в себе путь к файлу

Comment: всё что вы говорите конечно же верно и имеет смысл, я просто расчитывал на то, что возможно можно "сказать" IDE, что это не просто строка, а путь к файлу. как например мы делаем, когда комментируем переменную с помощью phpdoc @var и указываем IDE на тип переменной